# How to get and set CSRF Token in Angular 15.x to be able to make a post request to Laravel 10.x avoiding - Error 419 'CSRF token mismatch.'

Tags: post, request, csrf-token, angular15, laravel-10

i want to make the most simple post request to laravel server with angular but i get  Error 419  'CSRF token mismatch.'

i've tryed to put the token in the headers but i get the same result
i've tryed to put the token in the meta tag but i get the same result
i've tryed to make a delete requests but the same

only get method work fine

cors.php

```
  'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

//angular compnent
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.post('http://localhost/startSession',{})
    .subscribe({
      next:(res)=>{ console.log("Next",res) },
      error:(res)=>{console.log("Error",res)}
    });

//routes 
Route::post('/startSession', function () {
    return  response()->json("post");
});
```

i need just a database query